# How to group DIVs to one DIV using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have several DIVs with same class, and I need using jQuery or pure JS group it into one DIV

```
<div class="a">
    <div>1</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div>2</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

and I need it looks like:

```
<div class="new-class">
  <div class="a">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a">
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't change HTML, only can use JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `wrapAll` method

```js
$(".a").wrapAll("<div class='new-class'></div>")
```

```css
.new-class {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
    <div>1</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div>2</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to find information for 3 hours...

Answer (score 0):

$( ".inside-div-class" ).wrap('');

$("div").wrapAll('')